# React Webpack. Why do I get an error when calling a function from a child component?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I hope you can help. I've stripped down the code a lot to make the question easier to read.

The parent component passes the `renderHack()` function to the `selectBlock` component.

The function fires the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of null`

**Parent Component**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import SelectBlock from './SelectBlock.js';

export default class SiteFront extends React.Component {

  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
     jsonData : []
    };

  renderHack(){
    console.log("renderHack Fired.");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="inner">

          <SelectBlock
            renderHack={this.renderHack.bind(this)}
          />

        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

**Child Component**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

function submitHandler(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  this.props.renderHack();
};

export default class SelectBlock extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
    <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
      <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
    </form>
    );
  }
};
```

EDIT: Thanks to @azium. I changed `onSubmit={submitHandler}` to `onSubmit={submitHandler.bind(this}` and it worked.

I don't know what I am doing wrong. I haven't done a React build in a few months so I am a bit rusty. I thought this is correct though.

Your help is appreciated.
Thank you
Moe

Comment: in your `submitHandler` function, what would `this` be referring to? Are you sure you don't need that to be a method on the class `SelectBlock` ?

Comment: Do you mean inside the export default class Selectblock....{} component?

Comment: Yes I'm trying to give you a hint here without spelling the answer. outside of the class `this` isn't anything so it won't have props

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `submitHandler` into your class. It should look like this:

```
export default class SelectBlock extends React.Component {
  submitHandler(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.renderHack();
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <form onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
      <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
    </form>
    );
  }
};
```

The reason why you were getting an error was that `this` was equal to `null` inside `submitHandler`, [as it should be when a function is not called on an object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Using `submitHandler.bind(this)` is an alternate solution, but it feels more hacky than just having `submitHandler` be a method of your component class. In general, if you need access to props in a function called by your component, it should be a method of your component class so it can have access to `this.props` with no need for `bind`.

Comment: Correct answer. Thanks for the detailed response.